# Why does std::function accept a data member pointer?

Tags: c++, stl, c++20, std-function

This code is extracted and simplified from [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
 
struct Foo
{
    int num_;
};

int main()
{
    const Foo foo(314159);
     // store a call to a data member accessor
    std::function<int(Foo const&)> f_num = &Foo::num_;
    std::cout << "num_: " << f_num(foo) << '\n';
}
```

Why does this `std::function` accept a pointer to the data member, and why does `f_num(foo)` totally work?

I've checked that it used this constuctor:

```cpp
#if _USE_FUNCTION_INT_0_SFINAE
    template <class _Fx, typename _Mybase::template _Enable_if_callable_t<_Fx&, function> = 0>
#else // ^^^ _USE_FUNCTION_INT_0_SFINAE // !_USE_FUNCTION_INT_0_SFINAE vvv
    template <class _Fx, class = typename _Mybase::template _Enable_if_callable_t<_Fx&, function>>
#endif // _USE_FUNCTION_INT_0_SFINAE
    function(_Fx _Func) {
        this->_Reset(_STD move(_Func));
    }
```

https://godbolt.org/z/vTKfsWMhG

Comment: It's specifically designed to do so (it uses `std::invoke` under the hood), and the resulting function will return that member. Lets you do all kinds of clever things, like `std::ranges::sort` by a specific class member (by passing member-pointer to it as the projection) (it doesn't use `std::function`, but does use `std::invoke`).

Comment: A member data pointer attached to a proper object, results in a reference. The behaviour is similar to a unary accessor function called on an object. So std has decided to treat it like a unary function; except that you cannot normally call it with function call operator (`operator()`). It seemed convenient when they decided it. Nowadays it is recommended to wrap member bindings as lambdas for memory efficiency (`[object]{return object.data;}` or `[smart_ptr]{return smart_ptr->method();}`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `std::function` constructor accepts a pointer to a data member as it's *[Callable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Callable)*. This works because of the `std::invoke` under the hood.

Here's what happens:

- The `std::function` constructor takes the pointer to the data member.
- When you call `f_num(foo)`, it uses `std::invoke`, which knows how to handle pointers to data members. In this context, it treats the pointer as a function that takes an object and returns the referenced data member.
- This lets you perform operations like sorting by specific class members, providing a versatile way to work with class members.

The use of member pointers in this way is in accordance with the C++ standard, and allows for some powerful patterns in code.

Comment: While not false, this text sounds like the comments were copy-pasted into an AI that inserted some fluffy marketing speak.

Comment: May be the reason why the first comment has been removed

Comment: @j6t They have a lot of answers lately that follow this same format and get votes. By the looks they are either accepted or they fail to grasp the point of the question when it's more non-trivial.